# Changing the height of the table view when someone clicks on learn more

Tags: ios, swift

When someone clicks on learn more, I want to change the height of the tableview. I have the following code that gets called when someone clicks on learn more.

```
 @objc func expandDesc(sender: UIButton) {
        loadMoreDesc = !loadMoreDesc
        tableView.reloadData()
        tableView.sizeHeaderToFit()
    }
```

I'm also using the following code:

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        tableView.sizeHeaderToFit()
    }
    
    extension UITableView {
    func sizeHeaderToFit() {
        guard let headerView = tableHeaderView else { return }

        let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize).height

        var frame = headerView.frame
        
        // avoids infinite loop!
        if height != frame.height {
            frame.size.height = height
            headerView.frame = frame
            tableHeaderView = headerView
        }
    }
}
```

in viewDidLoad, I have the following code:

```
    tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 670
    tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

How do I make it so that when the person clicks on learn more, the table view header changes height to fit the content of its subviews? If all of its subviews are of a total length of 100, it should be length 100.

Comment: Is this for the header view or any generic cell?

Comment: This is the header view

Comment: Is this the same as your previous questions? Or are you not clearly describing what you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `loadMoreDesc` flag should be maintained separately from the header view, say in the `tableView` class itself, so that the flag will maintain across any `reloadData` calls and only change when the user taps the button.
2. Implement `viewForHeaderInSection` to return your header view.
3. Implement `heightForHeaderInSection` to return the proper height, based on your `loadMoreDesc` flag. Logic to estimate text height would be something like (assuming only the text is dynamic)

   ```
   func estimateHeight(ofText text: String) -> CGFloat {

       // Get the bounding width for the text
       let boundingWidth = view.frame.width - // something

       // Make the height of this estimated size arbitrarily large
       let estimatedSize = CGSize(width: boundingWidth, height: 1000)

       // Use the font your text has
       let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)] // Use the font your label has

       let estimatedHeight = NSString(string: text).boundingRect(with: estimatedSize, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributes, context: nil).height

       // Round up and return
       return estimatedHeight.rounded(.up)
   }
   ```
4. Now, when the user taps the show more or less button, call:

   ```
   @objc func expandDesc(sender: UIButton) {
       loadMoreDesc = !loadMoreDesc

       tableView.performBatchUpdates({
           self.collectionView?.reloadData()
       }, completion: { (didComplete) in
           // Other code once animation completes
       })
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi the thing is I can’t user viewFOrHeader to return the height because I don’t know the new length of the header. The header has content that changes in length. I don’t know what that new length is.

Comment: Is it only text?

Comment: the table view header has an image, text, button, the text dynamically changes in size

Comment: See edit to answer to allow you to determine the height of the text